# Postgres cast text[] to json[]

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a generated SQL statement that produces statements such as

```
array['{"foo": "bar"}']
```

This array obviously has the type `text[]`. What I need is a `json[]`, with the elements in the array being propper JSON objects, not just JSON strings.

I would like to add a cast for this. I have tried

```
select json_agg(t) from (select unnest(array['[{"unnest":{"foo": "bar"}}]'])::jsonb) t;
```

but this produces the incorrect result

```json
[{"unnest":{"foo": "bar"}}]
```

when the correct result would be

```json
[{"foo": "bar"}]
```

Comment: Well obviously the string `"unnest"` must be part of the result because it's part of your array that you are unnesting.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you start with `array['{"foo": "bar"}']` and then feed `array['[{"unnest":{"foo": "bar"}}]']` into your sample query.

---

It's typically better to move set-returning functions into the FROM clause:

```
select json_agg(t)
from (
  select x.element::jsonb as t
  from unnest(array['{"foo": "bar"}', '{"bar":"foo"}']) as x(element)
) t;
```

The above returns

```json
[{"foo": "bar"}, {"bar": "foo"}]
```